# How to export/import MacOS framework with cmake 3.14

Tags: macos, cmake, frameworks

I want to link a framework, that I made myself called VideoCapturer, to another project through its VideoCapturerConfig.cmake.
But I can't get the "usage requirement" / "target_link_libraries" correctly.

When I give the full path, hardcoded, to the location of the install framework, it works!

```
target_link_libraries( myprojectA
  PUBLIC -framework /install/path/to/videocapturer.framework )
```

I would rather do that with a *target* provided by find_package() for more robustness.

Here is the piece of CMake I wrote to build and install the framework

```
# MyVideoCapturer framework
project( MyVideoCapturer )

### General variables
set( myvideocapturer_targets_export_name "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets" )
set( myvideocapturer_config_install_dir  "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}" )
set( myvideocapturer_project_config      "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake" )
set( myvideocapturer_version_config      "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake" )

add_library( VideoCapturer "" )
add_library( MyVideoCapturer::VideoCapturer ALIAS VideoCapturer )

add_subdirectory( src ) # Mostly target_sources( VideoCapturer PRIVATE someSrcFiles.cpp )
list( APPEND _pubheaders "macVideoCapturer/VideoCapturer.h" )
set_target_properties( VideoCapturer PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${_pubheaders}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
    )

### Install targets, headers and export
include( GNUInstallDirs )
install(
  TARGETS VideoCapturer
  EXPORT "${myvideocapturer_targets_export_name}"
  FRAMEWORK DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
  )

install(
  EXPORT "${myvideocapturer_targets_export_name}"
  DESTINATION "${myvideocapturer_config_install_dir}"
  NAMESPACE MyVideoCapturer::
  FILE ${myvideocapturer_targets_export_name}.cmake
  )

### Config file for Packaging
include( CMakePackageConfigHelpers )
configure_package_config_file(
  "Config.cmake.in"
  "${myvideocapturer_project_config}"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${myvideocapturer_config_install_dir}
  PATH_VARS
    myvideocapturer_config_install_dir
  NO_SET_AND_CHECK_MACRO
  NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO
  )
```

in my *Config.cmake.in*

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@myvideocapturer_targets_export_name@.cmake" )
```

After installation of that framework :
in *MyVideoCapturerTargets.cmake* :

```
# Create imported target CppMacVideoCapturer::VideoCapturer
add_library(CppMacVideoCapturer::VideoCapturer SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET CppMacVideoCapturer::VideoCapturer PROPERTY FRAMEWORK 1)
```

to my understanding, 2 lines should be enough to get it right :

```
find_package( myvideocapturer REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries( myprojectA
  PUBLIC -framework videocapturer )
```

when I try that, the project can't find the headers located in Videocapturer.framework/Headers
and if I try :

```
target_link_libraries( myprojectA
  PUBLIC -framework MyVideoCapturer::myvideocapturer )
```

CMake doesn't find the target.

Any idea how can I export my framework ?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

Thanks to [tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) I found a way to solve it. I am not sure if this is the "proper" way to do it though.

In the base project :

```
if( APPLE )
  target_include_directories( VideoCapturer
    PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/VideoCapturer.framework>
    )
else() # Framework is Apple-only
  target_include_directories( VideoCapturer
    PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
    )
endif()
```

**EDIT 1/4/19** : the right way seems to do :

```
  target_include_directories( VideoCapturer
    PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/VideoCapturer.framework>
    )
```

**last edit** : Please read my own answer

Comment: "the project can't find the headers" - Not sure about framworks, but for normal libraries you should use [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_include_directories.html) in the base project, and provide `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:>` for your framework. By itself, `PUBLIC_HEADER` just mark given header as public, but do not adjust include directory.

Comment: All right! Thanks a lot. My mind was set on having this only valid value for the base project : $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>; which is incorrect for a framework. I tried to play with generator expression to have something flexible,but the evaluation inside INSTALL_INTERFACE is tricky. Something like this doesnt work: $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<IF:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:VideoCapturer,FRAMEWORK>,$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:VideoCapturer>.framework/Headers,include>> so I ended up doing: target_include_directories( VideoCapturer PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/VideoCapturer.framework/Headers> )

Comment: No needs to use *generator expressions* for *every* condition. Plain `if()` is much simpler in many cases. Generator expressions are intended to check features, which may depend on configuration type in multiconfiguration generators. That is, these features may be **not known at configuration stage**, when `CMakeLists.txt` code is executed. But target platform is always known during configuration. So you may freely use `if(MACOS)` for Macos-specific stuff.

Comment: Note that if you set `INCLUDES DESTINATION` in your `install(TARGETS...` command, CMake will take care of setting the `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:...>` path for you, so there's no need to specify it directly on the target. Not sure how that would interact with conditionalizing it via `if (APPLE)` and the like (I've never tried building frameworks), but it would probably be easier than trying to nest generator expressions. Avoiding those whenever you can is always smart thinkin'!

Answer (score 2):

The right way to install / export or package a framework is something like this : https://github.com/forexample/ios-dynamic-framework

However, it does contain a **workaround**, there is no find_package

This repository has a lot of good examples for "modern" CMake. check it out!